# Obtain initial value based on the text in first td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like so:

```
<table id="resultsTable">
  <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="subRow odd" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487186" data-auditid="f831583e-d1a9-4e35-ac92-82a5cb48c62e">
      <td class="  sorting_1">UserSelection</td>
      <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subRow even" data-activitylogid="6459056" data-auditidentity="18487179" data-auditid="88506880-632f-4e17-bceb-ebd4e20e435a">
      <td class="  sorting_1">Procedure</td>
      <td class=" "><a class="auditaction">Update</a></td>
    </tr>
```

I am attempting to get the auditidentity data value like so:

```
        var uniqueKeys = [];
        $('#resultsTable').find('tbody > tr').each(function() {

          var tableName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
          var tableAction = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
          var uniqueKey = tableName + '#' + tableAction;

          if (uniqueKeys.indexOf(uniqueKey) < 0) {
            uniqueKeys.push(uniqueKey);
          } else {
            //alert(tableName);
            //var initValue = $('#resultsTable tr td:first-child:contains(''' + tableName + ''')).data('auditidentity');
            //alert(initValue);
            var activityLogId = $(this).data('activitylogid');
            var auditidentity = $(this).data('auditidentity');
            var tableNameString = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var actionType = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
            //$(resultsTable).find('tbody > tr > td:first').contains(tableName).data('auditidentity', initValue + ',' + auditidentity);

            // After we have what we need, remove the combined row
            $(this).remove();
          }

        });
```

The commented out initValue line is not correct, and the console displays:

```
VM572:56 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )
```

For the life of me I cannot see why.  To be clear, what I am after is the first row's data where the first cell is a specific text value.

Comment: Logic makes no sense.... you already have reference to the row....and the cell you got the `tableName` from

Comment: @charlietfl I can see where you would think that, this was just a small part of a larger puzzle I am trying to solve.

Comment: Well it sure seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) based on using answer using `:contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related to the quotes; try using double quotes in your selector to avoid confusion with the multiple single quotes.

```
var initValue = $("#resultsTable tr td:first-child:contains('" + tableName + "')").parent().data('auditidentity');
```

Comment: That took care of the syntax issue ( thank YOU! ), but now I am getting undefined when I alert the value.

Comment: This is the answer:  var initValue = $("#resultsTable tr td:first-child:contains('" + tableName + "')").parent().data('auditidentity');  WOULD NOT have gotten there without your help.

Comment: .parent needed as I was on a child/sibling ( the td ) the row contained the data!  Add parent() to the answer and your the winner!